# storing base64 in localstorage

Tags: javascript

Well i have a function in javascript:

```
function store_data(){
var img=document.createElement("img"); 
/*var img=new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};*/
img.src= URL; //js global var
var height=parseInt(img.naturalHeight,10);
var width=parseInt(img.naturalWidth,10);
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); 
canvas.setAttribute("width", width);
canvas.setAttribute("height", height);

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(img,0,0);
canvas.style.width="100%"; 
var data=(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
localStorage.setItem("data", data);

}
```

The first time when is called store a string like "data;" in localStorage is incomplete the image is like a "data64;aotehtahotetav...". But when i call for second time the data is stored fine. Why happens that?

Perhaps i should load the image in a img of the dom loaded? The image is stored for using in draw late.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Michael has already mentioned your code is saving the image's data to localStorage before it has completely downloaded. The second time the image already exists in cache.

Maybe try loading the image onto the canvas when the onload event fires like so

```
function store_data() {

    var img = new Image();
    img.src =  URL; //js global var

    img.onload = function( ) {

        var canvas  =  document.getElementById( 'myCanvas' ); 
        canvas.setAttribute( "width", img.width );
        canvas.setAttribute( "height", img.height );

        var context  =  canvas.getContext( '2d' );
        context.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
        canvas.style.width = "100%"; 
        var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        localStorage.setItem( "data", data );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do your data storage in `img.onload`, then you cannot be certain that the image's data has been entirely downloaded when you're storing it in local storage, and you will get inconsistent data lengths.

Comment: I tried with this. Maybe is another trouble is a long long script.